# What does it mean in PHP to traverse arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, concept

I was wondering what does it mean in layman's terms to traverse php arrays

Answer (score 4):

To examine each element in turn, possibly performing an operation upon it.

Answer (score 4):

To *traverse a data structure* (regardless of programming language or specific data structure) is to "go through it". That is, in order to for instance inspect each element, transform every second element, remove each odd looking element, print each element and so on, you need to traverse the elements.